# Change number of columns in a grid by smooth transition as per browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small problem I'm facing in a simple HTML and CSS grid. I have a grid of n boxes. It can have any number of columns depending on the browser or its parent width.

It's very simple to apply display to inline-block as example below:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f00;
}​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2nscQ/

But when someone changes the width of the browser, I want the number of columns to change in a smooth transition. Is that possible with CSS? Or is there a good jQuery plugin or trick for it?

Example: http://www.squarespace.com/templates/

I'm looking for a very simple and small solution. Because I can't add a complete library for that small thing. I'm already using jQuery in my application. So if it's possible with CSS and jQuery. That'll be great.

Comment: What u mean at all..You want to make dynamic web page??

Comment: Content in grids(sections) could be dynamic or not. But width of grids and number of columns in grid should be dynamic(change according to width of browser). For reference have a look http://www.squarespace.com/templates/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make dynamic page of current browser changing. I decided you can check browser width by using `$(window).width()` in jQuery and you can use an event handler like `resize()` to attach browser width when the currently change by user... And something else: When we did it in CSS, most developers make dynamically website is set width by 100%.

**// This is example of CSS Media Queries I added:-**

CSS media queries can be added to CSS in all of the ways you're able to define it:

**First Example:** you link the specific CSS when the current page width is not higher and below 480px:

I'd recommend you use the first example. We know we can override the CSS grid, when the browser resizes you can set many time you want and with the difference file name you can make more `.css` file and link that like this below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="smallscreen.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
```

**Second Example:** imported stylesheet within the `<style>` element:

```
@import "smallscreen.css" only screen and (max-width: 480px);
```

**Third Example:** Within the `<style>` element as a media rule:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    /* rules defined inside here are only applied to browsers that support CSS media queries and the browser window is 480px or smaller */
  }
</style>
```

**... and then when you are working with specific browser you can use:**

**For Google Chrome:**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-animation) {
   div.grid_24 {
     // Webkit only rules 4
 } 
}
```

**Firefox:**

```
   @media screen and (max-width:320px;) {        
           div.grid_24 {
           //..
          }
       }
```

**... and Opera:**

```
 @media all (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
        div.grid_24{  
         //..
    }   // as i know maybe for opera 10 and above
```

**Or you can use for all:**

```
@media all and (max-width:480px) {
   div.grid_24 {
   //..
  }
}
```

That's all. If you want more reference about media query you can see [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), [htmlGoodies](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html) or [css-trick](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Buddy i know that even we not need jQuery for that we can achieve it by CSS only. My Question is columns should have to change by smooth transaction. See effect in example i send you before by reducing your browser width http://www.squarespace.com/templates/

Comment: oh..i think you can do with css3 keyframes check out of w3school -http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_keyframes.asp

Comment: Buddy may be i'm not able to explain you or may be you not read my question and saw 2 links i sent for clarification completely. Anyways thanks.

Comment: OK..Sorry about before, now i see what you mean..as i thought when we did in css dynamic webpages expectually on specific browser of  we want display  difference between browser to another browser we can use CSS Media Queries..... and i add the example above

Comment: Again you are not getting my question dude :(

Answer (score 0):

Surely just use [CSS3's `column-width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-width) property to set the width of the columns (presumably it will take `em` as a unit rather than `px`) and just put all the `li` items in one container with the column width set?

The w3schools example smoothly changes column count as I resize the browser window.

Comment: Thanks it's a nice solution. But my situation is little bit different. My main problem is that i want to keep same blocks(sections) as it is. Just have to shift it in other row during scale down browser and it should shift in next row with animation. Thanks again for above solution I can utilize it somewhere else :)